# factory_girl: Can we check if an attribute has been overridden in its lazy attribute block?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I would need to know if a factory caller supplied a value for an attribute (an override) in the attribute (lazy) block. Would be very useful when some attributes are inter-dependant.

```ruby
factory :shipping_item do
  quantity { % here, I would need to know if 'quantity' was overridden % }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: not in a supported / public API way.

According to this issue https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/583, the FactoryGirl author does not wish to support this feature.

Though not documented (and therefore even more subject to change) you can access the overriden parameters in the instance variable @overrides. It is a hash with symbol keys.

```
factory :shipping_item do
  quantity { @overrides[:other_attribute] || do_something_else }
end

# You can also even differentiate between the user
# not supplying an override at all, or supplying nil
# by checking @overrides.keys?(:other_attribute)
```

I don't quite understand your sample code though. Your code inside the block would already know if quantity was overridden, because otherwise the block wouldn't run!